# How to widen a vavr sequence?

Tags: vavr

I notice the [`narrow` method](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Seq.html#narrow-io.vavr.collection.Seq-) exists for sequences. How would one go about doing the opposite, going from sequence of a subclass to a sequence of a superclass in a type-safe manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Seq.narrow()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/collection/Seq.html#narrow-io.vavr.collection.Seq-) does exactly that: going from a sequence of some type `T` to a sequence of a supertype `S` of that type `T`.

The following example compiles:

```java
class Superclass {}
class Subclass extends Superclass {}

class Test {
    void test() {
        Seq<Subclass> subs = List.of(new Subclass(), new Subclass());
        Seq<Superclass> supers = Seq.narrow(subs);
        // both 'subs' and 'supers' are safe to use
    }
}
```

This works because vavr collections are immutable, so when you have a `Seq<T>` you can be sure that all values in the sequence are also values of type `S`. Since you cannot change a vavr collection, *narrowing* a reference to `Seq<T>` to `Seq<S>` is always safe (`T` being a subtype of `S`), since you can never change the original `Seq<T>` by adding a value of type `S` into it. That would violate the type safety of the original `Seq<T>`, as now it would contain an element which is not `T`. Note that this cannot be guaranteed for mutable collections, so all such *narrowing* of mutable collections would be inherently unsafe.